# Finding a function from a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I have to find the explicit expression of the function $f$, knowing that:
$$\int_{0}^{x} f(t) \,dt = xe^{2x}+\int_{0}^{x} e^{-t}f(t) \,dt$$

I've recognized the integration by parts pattern in the right side of the equation, but I'm not able to move forward. Can you help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hint: what do you get after differentiating both sides with respect to $x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first instinct when seeing a function under an integral is to differentiate it outside. Thus, taking derivatives with respect to $x$ on both sides of the equation, we get:
$$
f(x) = e^{2x} + 2xe^{2x} + e^{-x} f(x)
$$
Then, by rearranging and solving for $f(x)$, we get:
$$
f(x) = \frac{e^{2x}(1 + 2x)}{1 - e^{-x}}
$$
Strictly speaking, one should also worry about the convergence of these integrals since there is a discontinuity at zero, but that may be outside the scope of this problem, and informally speaking those discontinuities can be seen to "cancel" out on each side of the equation.

Comment: Your concern about the convergence of the integral is quite relevant because the integrals are actually divergent, rendering the initial expression meaningless for any $x\ne 0$. The correct answer would be that there is no such function $f$.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a derivative of both sides of the equation gives

$$ f(x) =  \frac{(1 + 2 x)e^{2x}}{1 - e^{-x}}$$

which should be the answer.

Comment: When we differentiate both sides, we are saying that, if the initial equality is satisfied, so is the differentiated equality. This is just a one direction implication and the solution must be verified. As it turns out, this expression for $f$ leads to divergent integrals in the original equality.

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in other answers, by differentiating the original equality, we conclude that the only expression that could work is
$$
f(x)=\dfrac{(2x+1)e^{2x}}{1-e^{-x}}.
$$

However, this candidate solution must be verified and, as it turns out, it leads to divergent integrals in the original equality. The final conclusion is that there exists no function $f$ in such conditions (at least not when the regularity of $f$ allows differentiation of the equality).